# Code not following sequential order in source

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox, oledbconnection

I have a settings form, on which lies a combobox that I would like to fill on load of the form with data returned from an access database.

Where I'm having difficulty is actually setting the combobox's datasource - when the program executes, it jumps from filling the OleDbDataAdapter to loading the form; skipping code.

Here's my latest code:

Form Load

```
        private void frm_settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Divisions divs = new Divisions();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        ds = divs.GetActiveDivisions(); //jumps from here to loading the form
        this.cmbo_divisions.DataSource = ds; //this never gets invoked
    }
```

And the Divisions class

```
    class Divisions
{
    private string error;

    public string Error //read only
    {
        get { return this.error; }
    }

    public DataSet GetActiveDivisions()
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

        PinnacleConnection Pconn = new PinnacleConnection();
        string sql = "SELECT ID, title FROM Divisions WHERE active = true;";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //connect to db
        conn = Pconn.createConnection();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error handling here
            this.error = ex.Message;
            return ds;
        }

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds); //!!jumps from here to loading the form!!
        conn.Close(); //never gets invoked?
        return ds; //never gets invoked?
    }
}
```

As you can see by my comments, the execution skips the setting of the datasource on the cmbo_divisions object... resulting in an empty combobox.

I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably throwing an exception. First, you should turn on the "halt on exception" stuff in the debugger, which will make it easier to find these kind of issues. Also, you probably want a try-catch around *all* of the database code (you might also need some `using` statements too.

Comment: I imagine you're erroring, and returning the empty `DataSet` from your catch

Comment: when I step through the code, the catch statement isn't executed though...

Comment: use this: this.cmbo_divisions.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

Comment: Ok See my proposed posted answer as it is more elaborated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a dataset, a datatable is more sutable for this:

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
...
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

and the binding will to the datatable directly, so you can avoid datasets whenever possible as they are more heavy objects:

```
this.cmbo_divisions.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guesses would be that `adapter.Fill` throws an exception or contains a message pump. So test for those scenarios first.